# Wrong datetime datetime.strptime('01/01/2017 00:03', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

Tags: python, string, datetime

Im trying to convert a string to datetime, but i'm getting the below error.

```
time_ = ad_status_df['updated_at'][2]
datetime.strptime(time_, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

output:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-ad92608b3939> in <module>
----> 1 datetime.strptime(time_, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    357     if not found:
    358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '2020-06-30 03:00:04' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking on the check mark. Thank you!

Comment: you're supplying the wrong date format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error message itself:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-06-30 03:00:04' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

This means that `time` is not in the format `%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S`.

You could either:

- provide the time in the format `2020/06/30 03:00:04`, or
- set the "format" argument of `strptime()` to `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`:

```
time_ = ad_status_df['updated_at'][2]
datetime.strptime(time_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: thanks, worked fine, i was overlooking to the letters Y, m, d and forgot about the separators

Comment: Yeah, that happens... I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

As the error says the variable date is in format %Y-%m-%d you just need to change '/' with '-'